# Missing emoji in ITextSharp export pdf

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I search a lot of links in google but not found any valuable docs for it.

I want to export pdf file using ITextSharp library that contains Persian, English, Emoji and special characters
and this my code:

```
public PdfGenerator( BaseFont bf = null)
{
    _bf = bf ?? BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\iransans.ttf",
              BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

}
```

...

```
var fontNormal = new Font(_bf, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.Black);
```

...

```
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, text, fontNormal))
{
   RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
   BorderWidth = 0,
   Padding = 20,
   Colspan = isLongText ? 3 : 2,
   CellEvent = new RoundedBorder2()
});
```

I also change my fonts to official and well-known fonts but not change result and 
my export file missing emojis and spec character